# elasticsearch group by based on every n rows

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a question in `elasticsearch`

I'm using `single node elasticsearch 7.17.7`

I have a table like this

| name | age | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benjamin | 15 | 44 |
| William | 17 | 60 |
| Jo | 22 | 85 |
| Sophia | 13 | 86 |
| Bob | 16 | 90 |
| Smith | 19 | 93 |
| Luck | 17 | 95 |
| John | 15 | 98 |
| Henry | 25 | 99 |

**My Question**

I want to `sort` by `score` field then `average` every `3` rows on field `age`

**I want this result**

| age |
| --- |
| `(15+17+22)/3` = 18 |
| `(13+16+19)/3` = 16 |
| `(17+15+25)/3` = 19 |

Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: This is not really possible to do inside elasticsearch. You can sort by score but you and even calculate rolling average, but you would have to group yourself. Which problem are you trying to solve? Would grouping by age ranges help you here?

Comment: thanks for answer - but its not about range . just about grouping every n sequence rows .  I can't use range .  I want to implement  `sql row_number`  in elastic then with using `histogram` maybe solve.